# Spring Boot: How to access locale in Services or Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, locale

I followed some tutorials for internationalization in Spring Boot.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7pHhui0cD4 and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization)

I came so far to configure it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class InternationalizationConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean 
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

and to use it in the RestConroller like this:

```
@RestController
public class ExperimentalControllerImpl implements ExperimentalController{

    @Autowired
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public String testI18n(@RequestHeader("Accept-Language") String locale) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(messageSource.getMessage(Messages.HELLO, null, new Locale(locale)));
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append(messageSource.getMessage(Messages.HOW_ARE_YOU, null, new Locale(locale)));
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

It works fine.....

**But how do I get the locale information from the request header to my service layer or my repository layers?**

Is there a **best practise** to store the information which locale is sent by the request, so that I can access it in my services and repositories? I think the value must be **request/thread specific**. Giving it as a method parameter down to the other layer seems pretty ugly.

Thank you
Regards form Germany

Comment: Code is code, not pictures. (Additionally, link to these "some tutorials" as it appears they may not be entirely reliable; Boot already does some of what you posted.)

Comment: In your controller you are already doing it wrong. Just inject `Locale` into the method. If you need it somewhere else use `LocalContextHolder.getLocale()`. However the `MessageSource` already does that internally so instead of passing it, just pass `null`.

Comment: Hi Deinum, injecting Locale into the Method? ```public String testI18n(Local locale) {}``` does not work. The injected locale is always 'de', even when I put 'en' in my request header (Accept-Language), propably because its the default. ```LocalContextHolder.getLocale()``` delivers 'de' all the time too. I need the Locale that is sent in the request, to throw internationalized exception messages in the service layer. What am I doing wrong?